# Recorrer un array de un modelo (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, lumen

Tengo una clase Roles donde defino un array estático como este

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

class Role extends EntrustRole
{

    public static $roles = [
        'admin1aaa' => [
            'name' => 'admin2aaa',
            'display_name' => 'Usuario admin',
            ] ,
        'secretary' => [
            'name' => 'secretary',
            'display_name' => 'Usuario de secretaria',
        ],
        'teacher' => [
            'name' => 'teacher',
        ]
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','display_name','description'
    ];

    /**
     * Get all users a role belongs to.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Lo que intento hacer es comprobar si los elementos del `array` de roles que se encuentra en `Role::$roles` sino existe los elementos en la tabla que los inserte, el problema que tengo que tanto `Role::$roles` como `Role::all()` tengo la sensación que va a buscar el `array` del modelo , y lo que necesito es que en un caso lo haga del `array` del modelo y en el otro caso lo haga de la tabla de la base da datos.. pero no veo como hacerlo

```php
public function createRoles()
    {
        $countDone =0;
        $countFail =0;

        foreach (Role::$roles as $key => $value) {

            $role = Role::all()->find('name',$value['name']);

            if ($role === null) {

                $owner = new Role();
                $owner->name = $value['name'];
                $owner->display_name = $value['display_name'];

                if ($owner->save())
                    $countDone++;
                else
                    $countFail++;
            }
        }


        return $this->jsonCreatedResponse('Roles created correctly : '.$countDone . ' Failed : '. $countFail);
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer por lo que lei recorres los arreglos de tu propiedad estatica y los vas creando en caso de que no existan, hay algo de error en eso????

Comment: Yo sinceramente tampoco entiendo que pretendes. Aunque posible el modelo no está pensado para eso. Si necesitas crear determinados roles en la bd a la hora de desplegar por primera vez lo mejor seria utilizar un seeder para hacerlo. Otra opción podría ser declarar el Array en el controlador de roles para no ensuciar el modelo con algo que no le corresponde.

Answer (score 0):

Hola, antes que nada, creo que deberías darle la siguiente forma a tu arreglo `$roles`:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

class Role extends EntrustRole
{

    public static $roles = [
            'admin'     => [
                ['name' => 'admin', 'display_name' => 'Usuario admin'],
            ],
            'secretary' => [
                ['name' => 'secretary', 'display_name' => 'Usuario de secretaria'],
            ]
        ];
```

Luego, puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```php
    // mapeando arreglo
    $roles_to_check = collect(Role::$roles)->flatten(1);
    // obteniendo roles existentes
    $roles_existentes = Role::whereIn('name', $roles_to_check->pluck('name'))
        ->get()
        ->map(function ($role) {
            return [
                'name'         => $role->name,
                'display_name' => $role->display_name,
            ];
        });
    // creando arreglo de nuevos roles
    $roles_to_add = $roles_to_check->whereNotIn('name', $roles_existentes->pluck('name'));
    // creando nuevos roles
    $roles_to_add->each(function ($newRole) {
        $owner = Role::create([
                'name'         => $newRole['name'],
                'display_name' => $newRole['display_name'],
            ]);
    });

    return $this->jsonCreatedResponse('Roles created correctly: ' . $roles_to_add->count());
```

Básicamente lo que este código hace es evitar hacer consultas recurrentes a la base de datos para saber si el rol existe o no (como estabas haciendo en tu `foreach`), para lograr esto:

1. Obtengo los roles existentes
2. Comparo todo los elementos de tu arreglo con los existentes en la base de datos para saber los nuevos a añadir.
3. Añado los elementos.

---

PD: Los comentarios que te hicieron son correctos, debes ser algo más específico al momento de hacer tus consultas. Me ha tomado bastante tiempo descifrar lo que intentas hacer (y eso que aún no estoy seguro de que sea lo que he asumido).